# E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid. - CreateDevice

Tags: c++, windows-8, directx

I have a d3dDevice:

```
ComPtr<ID3D11Device1>d3dDevice;
```

I use it here for the dxgiDevice:

```
    ComPtr<IDXGIDevice3> dxgiDevice2;

    HRESULT hr;

    hr = d3dDevice.As( &dxgiDevice2 ); // S_OK

    hr = d2dFactory->CreateDevice( dxgiDevice2.Get(), d2dDevice.GetAddressOf() ); // E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid

    hr = d2dDevice->CreateDeviceContext(
        D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE,
        &d2dDeviceContext
        );
```

Why might this error be happening on runtime?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280482(v=vs.85).aspx

Entirety of my code that is relevant to problem: http://pastebin.com/P7Rs9xdh

Comment: Did you try `&d2dDevice`?

Comment: @ichramm Why? There's nothing wrong with that `GetAddressOf` syntax - it's actually how MS shows its example code now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't created your DX11 device to be compatible with Direct2D. You need to pass the correct creation flags and you should also consider defining the required feature level. Something like:

```
// This flag adds support for surfaces with a different color channel 
// ordering than the API default.
// You need it for compatibility with Direct2D.
UINT creationFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

// This array defines the set of DirectX hardware feature levels this 
// app supports.
// The ordering is important and you should  preserve it.
// Don't forget to declare your app's minimum required feature level in its
// description.  All apps are assumed to support 9.1 unless otherwise stated.
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
};

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL m_featureLevel;

// Create 3D device and device context objects
D3D11CreateDevice(
    nullptr,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    nullptr,
    creationFlags,
    featureLevels,
    ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &d3dDevice11,
    &m_featureLevel,
    &d3dDeviceContext11);
```

Comment: ARGHHHHHHHHHH, Ofcourseeeeee... let me try when I get home. if this is correct, I will KISS YOU, you schmexy man you!

Comment: Don't be shy now... hah. I look forward to doing this though.. not the kiss, I mean seeing if it works. Will keep you updated!